# Novice here: How can I populate an workflow email with text from another Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email

I am creating a notification email to go out to the users of my site, to let them know there is a new InfoPath form they need to complete. I understand how to bring in dynamic fields like their name, due date etc, However, I want the actual body of the email to be populated from columns in a specific list, rather than just typing it into the email window in the workflow. (So that we can make it easy for a non-SharePoint user to edit the email content). Can someone advise me on how to do this please?

PS: I am very new to SharePoint/SP Designer, so please be very detailed.

And also if anyone feels like answering this too: I am also trying to find the URL for my InfoPath form to also add to the email - so the recipient can just click on the link and open their personalized form.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you click the Add or Change Lookup button in the Define E-mail Message dialog, you can select the list that contains the email text as the Data Source.  Select the Field which contains the text for the Field From Source.  To find the list item, just choose ID for the field, and type in the ID for the item containing the email text.

As for your second question, you can find InfoPath template at:

List: `<site url>/Lists/<internallistname>/<templatename>.xsn` (not 100% on this)

Library: `<site url>/<library>/Forms/<templatename>.xsn`.

However, using that link will likely prompt for a download.  You'll have to use the following to save to list/library:

`<site url>/_layouts/15/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=<templateUrl>&SaveLocation=<encoded url to save location>&ClientInstalled=true&DefaultItemOpen=1` (not sure about the last two parameters).

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason it isn't working though. Does it matter that my email workflow is in one list, and the text I'm trying to bring in is from a different list? Its bringing in the 'code'/shorthand so it LOOKS like its brought the text into the email, but then when I test it the email is blank.

Comment: No, it should not matter that they're in separate lists.  Does the list you're bringing the email text from have any other fields? Try getting a different field, say the created date.  If it shows up null, it's possible you're not grabbing the list item containing the email.